# Tree view display JS for angular/bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Any pointers for a good Tree view display js which could work along with angular/bootstrap?

Comment: I use jstree along with Bootstrap.  https://github.com/vakata/jstree

Comment: If you google angular tree, this is first result :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854514/is-it-possible-to-make-a-tree-view-with-angular