# AngularJS - Controller of my partial

Tags: javascript, templates, model-view-controller, controller, angularjs

I've a template that is appendend many times in my DOM.

```
<div ng-controller="theController">
    content does not matter
</div>
```

So the controller is istantiated many times.
This is a problem because if i put a watcher in the controller

```
theController = function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('myVar', function() {
        // run one time for each time the template is repeated
    })
}
```

Any ideas about how to avoid this?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

OK, i will try to be clearer.

Perhaps i've a form, that is built dynamically on the basis of the response of an asynchronous request.

```
<form ng-controller="formController">
    <div ng-repeat="f in fields">
        <ng-inclide src="f.fields"></ng-include>
    </div>
</form>
```

The controller is something like:

```
function formController($scope) {
    $scope.fields = [{ template:'', ... }];
    // data come from an ajax request... 
    // here are static for the sake of simplicity.
}
```

So I don't know what fields will be appended in the form.

The form field structure is stored in html partials... something like:

```
<div ng-controller="inputController">
    <label> .... </label>
    <input type="text" .... />
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-controller="selectController">
    <label> .... </label>
    <select>
        ....
    </select>
</div>

function selectController($scope){
    $scope.$on("myCustomEvent", function(event) {
        cionsole.info("Options were updated");
    });
}
```

When the form has more than an `input type=text`, or a `select`, the `inputController`, or the `selectController` are instantiated more than once.

**Why do you not want the $watch to occur for every instance?**

I would like to update the options of one of the selects in the page when a specific event occurs.

What i get is instead that i update all the select in the page.

*From the comment, i understood that is wrong to have more element with the same controller in the same page.*
**So currently the only available solution seem to me that is to avoid to define a controller for each element of the form, right?**

**UPDATE 2**

`$emit` is used in the **inputController**:

```
function inputController() {
    $scope.fireclick = function(p) {
        if (p == 'specificInput') {
            /* this is a temporary work around 
            I used to bind the event only with a specific field */

            $scope.$emit("myCustomEvent");      
        }
    }
}
```

This is the complete code of the input field used in the html partial:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="fireclick(f.name);" name="{{f.name}}" />
```

@Anybody:

**Could at least confirm, (and eventually say why), to have on the same page more elements with the same controller is wrong**

Comment: Controller instances cannot (and should not) be shared across multiple elements. What are you trying to do and why do you *not* want the `$watch` to occur for every instance? Controllers are inherently local to where you're using them in the DOM - they are not application-wide - so if having the `$watch` fire multiple times is an issue, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: is the event a boradcast/emit

Comment: @ArunPJohny I used $rootScope.$emit('myCustomEvent')

Comment: who is firing this event, is it within the form or from somewhere elese

Comment: Can you share the code which is firing the event

Comment: @ArunPJohny could at least confirm that have more than an element with the same controller is wrong?

Comment: no, it should not be a problem

Comment: In your usage the problem seems to be you don't have defined audience for the event, you are emitting the event from root scope to all children

Comment: How could you define the event fired by input `x` has to be captured by only select `y`

Comment: So, perhaps, do you know also how could i solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do a form with recursive fields (based on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663410/1036025)

Result [[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voqt8.png)]:

[image]

The **view controller** which loads the Home.html partial with a ng-view:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.msg = 'Home Page Message';
}]);
```

The **form controller** which is inside Home.html:

```
app.controller('NestedFormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.formData = [
        {label:'First Name', type:'text', required:'true'},
        {label:'Last Name', type:'text', required:'true'},
        {label:'Coffee Preference', type:'dropdown', options: ["HiTest", "Dunkin", "Decaf"]},
        {label: 'Address', type:'group', Fields:[
            {label:'Street1', type:'text', required:'true'},
            {label:'City', type:'text', required:'true'},
            {label:'State', type:'dropdown',  options: ["California", "New York", "Florida"]}
        ]}
    ];

    $scope.$watch('formData[3].Fields[1].label', function(newval, oldval) {
        if (oldval !== newval) {
            console.log('watch', oldval, newval);
        }
    });

    // this was added after and is not shown in the image
    $scope.$watch('formData', function(newval, oldval) {
        if (oldval !== newval) {
            console.log('watch', oldval, newval);
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.changefield = function() {
        $scope.formData[3].Fields[1].label = 'Postal Code';
    }

    $scope.customevent = function(field) {
        var type = field.type;
        // do something for this type
        console.log('customevent', field);
    };
}]);
```

The **Home partial view** (here the template path in ng-include could be a property of your fields or you may use a switch case and display the input/select of your choice:

```
<h1>{{msg}}</h1>
<ul ng-controller="NestedFormCtrl">
    <li><button ng-click="changefield()">Change</button></li>
    <li ng-repeat="field in formData" ng-include="'views/field.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

The **field.html template** (either have one template per type of field, or one main template with a switch case on the field.type property)

```
<button ng-click="customevent(field)">{{field.label}}</button>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="field in field.Fields" ng-include="'views/field.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer... could you share please also the code of views/field.html?

Comment: It is the last block of code! It includes itself for recursion, but you first include it in your main view.

Answer (score 5):

I think the Angular Way to do this is to use directives.  I would do something like an ng-switch in your main view's ng-repeat, and have the ng-switch just include the appropriate directive... Assuming an "input-text" directive an an "input-dropdown" directive exist:

```
<div ng-swtich on="field.type" ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <div ng-switch-when="text"><input-text ...></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="dropdown"><input-dropdown ...></div>
</div>
```

I *believe* this way you will not have the same issue you're having now.  I haven't actually setup what you're trying to do, but I'm 99% certain that you should be using directives!  They are ideal for the type of thing you're doing, and will be much more re-usable.

I use a directive on http://angularlist.com to handle the ratings, and I can confidently say they don't cross wires when I have more than one on the page - That said, I'm not watching anything there, just responding to events... Actually, let me test something (testing.........) Yes! I added a watch to the model value the my ratings directive is editing and when clicking on a rating, only ONE watcher is fired - the one for the controller in question.  This isn't on the live site, just my dev server here at home, but here's the directive if it helps you:

```
app.directive("angularStars", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      notifyId: '=notifyId'
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><ol class="angular-stars">' + '<li ng-class="{active:model>0,over:over>0}">1</li>' + '<li ng-class="{active:model>1,over:over>1}">2</li>' + '<li ng-class="{active:model>2,over:over>2}">3</li>' + '<li ng-class="{active:model>3,over:over>3}">4</li>' + '<li ng-class="{active:model>4,over:over>4}">5</li>' + '</ol></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs, $http) {
      $scope.over = 0;

      // TEST WATCH
      $scope.$watch('model', function() {
        console.log('modelChange', $scope.model);
      });

      $scope.setRating = function(rating) {
        $scope.model = rating;
        $scope.$apply();
        if ($attrs.notifyUrl !== void 0 && $scope.notifyId) {
          return $http.post($attrs.notifyUrl, {
            id: $scope.notifyId,
            rating: rating
          }).error(function(data) {
            if (typeof data === 'string') {
              alert(data);
            }
            return $scope.model = 0;
          });
        }
      };
      return $scope.setOver = function(n) {
        $scope.over = n;
        return $scope.$apply();
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
      if (iAttrs.notifyUrl !== void 0) {
        return angular.forEach(iElem.children(), function(ol) {
          return angular.forEach(ol.children, function(li) {
            li.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
              return scope.setOver(parseInt(li.innerHTML));
            });
            li.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
              return scope.setOver(0);
            });
            return li.addEventListener('click', function() {
              return scope.setRating(parseInt(li.innerHTML));
            });
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Directives are tough to get your head wrapped around - I am still mainly just shooting in the dark with them, trying things out to see how they work - but no doubt - the power you need is in the directives.  I highly recommend reading the [AngularJS docs on writting directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and then spending time looking at other people's directives - there are many available on GitHub to learn from!

Comment: I would use directives for every repeatable object too.

Comment: @Thom, can you please explain usage of return statements in this code?  I never seen such technique before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plunk to help you along for this scenario ...

http://plnkr.co/edit/RvFrmPd4rlAM8aeFSwg7?p=preview

This is just an illustration of how this can be achieved. Without knowing how much control you have over the form config data its not really possible to provide a more comprehensive answer. Between if you want to know, its better to inject $rootScope wherever you want to do a $broadcast ( $emit goes up the DOM tree while $broadcast goes down.. So $broadcasting from $rootScope will reach the whole app. )

Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: absolutely perfectly what i was looking for, +1