# How to build a nested tree in AngularJS with recursive inclusion

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a few in AngularJS that recursively includes itself.  Each `WorkflowProcess` has children `WorkflowProcess` and I'd like the tree to be infinitely included.

Currently it looks like:

[image]

It should be displaying...

```
Approval
   |
   ---------
           |
      Impositioning
```

Here's my template:

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="workflow" ng-options="workflow.name for workflow in workflows"></select>
</div>
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <div ng-repeat="workflowProcess in workflow.workflowProcesses" ng-include="'/partials/admin/workflow-tree-node.htm'"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**workflow-tree-note.html**

```
<li ng-repeat="childWorkflowProcess in workflowProcess.workflowProcesses">
    <a>{{childWorkflowProcess.entity.name}}</a>
    <ul>
        <ng-include src="'/partials/admin/workflow-tree-node.htm'" />
    </ul>
</li>
```

It's displaying "Impositioning" over and over.  I'm recognizing that that's because the loop in the html is referencing the same data.  I'm not sure how to make it just reference the next tier of data.

Every workflow has a property `workflowProcesses`.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661289/how-can-i-make-recursive-templates-in-angularjs-when-using-nested-objects.  The fiddle in the approved answer was enough for me to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to change

```
<li ng-repeat="childWorkflowProcess in workflowProcess.workflowProcesses">
<a>{{childWorkflowProcess.entity.name}}</a>
```

to

```
<li ng-repeat="workflowProcess in workflowProcess.workflowProcesses">
<a>{{workflowProcess.entity.name}}</a>
```

To have the variable replaced by it's child in the subtree.