# Can angular directives call themselves?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some sample data in JSON format:

```
{
  "menus" : [
    {"name" : "Item 1", "children" : [
      {"name" : "Item 1.1", "url" : "http://www.website.com1/1"},
      {"name" : "Item 1.2", "url" : "http://www.website.com1/2"},
      {"name" : "Item 1.3", "children": [
        {"name" : "Item 1.3.1", "url" : "http://www.website.com1/3/1"},
        {"name" : "Item 1.3.2", "url" : "http://www.website.com1/3/2"},
        {"name" : "Item 1.3.3", "url" : "http://www.website.com1/3/3"}
      ]}
    ]},
    {"name" : "Item 2", "children": [
      {"name" : "Item 2.1", "url" : "http://www.website.com2/1"},
      {"name" : "Item 2.2", "url" : "http://www.website.com2/2"},
      {"name" : "Item 2.3", "url" : "http://www.website.com2/3"}
    ]},
    {"name" : "Item 3", "url" : "http://www.website.com3"}
  ]
}
```

I want to build a menu tree that matches the stucture of the JSON.  So I made a directive:

```
app.directive('menuItem',
function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope: { data : '='},
        replace:true,
        templateUrl: 'directives/menu-item.html'
    };  
});
```

I add the directive to my HTML and it works great for the first layer:

```
<menu-item data="menu.data.menus"></menu-item>
```

What I want to happen is that if model the directive is using has a 'children' property, I want it to build a new node using the same template as itself:

```
<ul class="menu-items" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        <div ng-if="item.children.length">
                    <!-- when I add this line I get problems -->
            <menu-item data="item.children"></menu-item>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I get the following error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.13/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Question is, how can I get the desired functionality, and how should I think about what's going on to understand this better?

*Fiddle to come...*

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854514/is-it-possible-to-make-a-tree-view-with-angular

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle recursive rendering of data using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415142/how-to-handle-recursive-rendering-of-data-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Thanks.  Yes this was in fact the same issue adressed in [How to handle recursive rendering of data using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415142/how-to-handle-recursive-rendering-of-data-using-angularjs)

For this particular case, it would be important to mention that in it's present formulation the template would need to use **"ng-init"** to properly recurse.

```
<ul class="menu-items" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        <div ng-include="'directives/menu-item.html'" ng-init="data = item.children" class="submenu-item"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```