# ng-include not working with script type="text/ng-template"

Tags: angularjs

Here is my Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/oIei6gAU1Bxpo8VUIswt

When the button is clicked, the following should be inserted before the "Hello World!" span:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tempTest">
  <div>
    <span>Properly Inserted</span> 
  </div>
</script>
```

minus the script tags, of course.

I achieve this by dynamically inserting the following div:

```
<div ng-include="tempTest"></div>
```

And then compiling it.  However, if you look at the log, the only thing that is left after the compilation is this:

```
<!-- ngInclude: tempTest -->
```

What is going on here?  Why isn't my insert properly compiling?  the logic is as follows:

```
$scope.insert = function(){
    // Create elements //
    var container = angular.element('<div id="compiled-container"></div>');
    var element = angular.element('<div ng-include="tempTest"></div>');

    //Insert parent Container
    $('#greeting').before(container);

    // insert the element
    $animate.enter(element, container);

    // test insertion
    console.log("Before Compile: " +container.html() )

    $compile(element);

    //look again after compile
    console.log("After Compile:  " +container.html() )

};
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The **quick** answer might have been:

> `<div ng-include="'tempTest'"></div>` 
>   Probably you just forgot the single quotes to reference the template.

The **long** answer:

It is not advised to access the DOM inside a controller - you will get in trouble as the code will be flooded with `$scope.$apply()` calls. Think about implementing this feature with a directive. I tried to create a starting point from your code here

http://plnkr.co/UWUCqWuB9d1dn6Zwy3J3

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.directive('greeting', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    template: '<div>'+
              '  <span>Hello {{name}}!</span>'+
              '  <button ng-click="insert()">test</button>'+
              '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.insert = function() {
         var container = angular.element('<div ng-include="\'tempTest.html\'"></div>');
         element.before($compile(container)(scope));
       }
    }
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```
<greeting name="name"></greeting>
```

The template elements are inserted before the Hello World! textnode everytime the button is clicked.

**Side note** You dont even need the `scope{ name: '='}` as the directive will inherit its surrounding scope, but its the cleaner way to pass (actually bind) controller variables to a directive explicitly.

Comment: Not only were you correct about the single quotes around the template ID, I also saw in your great example that I didn't have this line correct: `$compile(element)($scope);`.  I didn't have the `($scope)` portion.  Also, you are absolutely correct about the Directive.  In fact, my actual code is in a directive.  I was just trying to throw an example of my problem together as fast as possible.  Your Directive has some interesting elements that i'm going to make use of in my own, however, so thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: is it possible to reference an ng-template text template living on another html file? How does angular know how to a template if it's not on the same file or has been previously loaded?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-include src="tempTest"></div>
```

This should work

^^^ note that this will **NOT** even begin to work unless single quotes are added (as @JHixson has already pointed out), like so:

```
<div ng-include src="'tempTest'"></div>
```

Comment: tempTest needs to have single quotes around it, like in the accepted answer.

Comment: My downvote stands (in my mind); the original response is incorrect enough to be misleading to folks unaware of the necessary syntax.

Comment: It actually works *just fine* without single quotes, if the string passed in references a String containing the correct url

Answer (score 0):

Simply your script :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tempTest">
  <div>
    <span>Properly Inserted</span> 
  </div>
</script>
```

Must be inside the **MainCtrl** controller selector like this :

```
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tempTest">
<div>
<span>Properly Inserted</span> 
</div>
</script>
</div>
```