# Change AngularJS version in Hawtio

Tags: angularjs, hawtio

I have Hawtio web console for Karaf (or JBoss Fuse) homepage and I also have an AngularJS app as a plugin in the Hawtio. Is it possible to change the version of AngularJS library built-in (or packaged) in Hawtio? I need a more recent functionality (ng-repeat-start-end) of AngularJS which does not work when deployed as a Hawtio plugin.

Answer (score 1):

hawtio is kinda stuck on 1.1.5 at the moment as we've a patch that enables the dashboard functionality.  However you can easily implement the same functionality via ng-include and a template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
    <div>
        <header>{{item.foo}}</header>
        <footer>{{item.bar}}</footer>
    </div>
</script>
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'myTemplate.html'"></div>
```

Note the ' in the ng-include directive config, otherwise you hit [ng-include not working with script type="text/ng-template"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149653/ng-include-not-working-with-script-type-text-ng-template)

Comment: I need `ng-repeat-start-end` to use on every two rows. Can I use a directive instead with templateUrl that encloses two <tr>'s?

Comment: Yeah, so looks like if I had a case like that I'd write a simple directive to handle inserting the two rows of data like that.  Though to be honest, I wonder if a <table> is the right layout approach for displaying the data?  Another option is to use bootstrap's grid layout instead which doesn't constrain you to the markup structure that a <table> does.