# Angular js create dynamic menu using json

Tags: angularjs, html

I am new to angular js .I need to create a dynamic menu and hyperlink using angular js.
I have menu name and hyperlink coming from json and i need to display.
Currently i have tried with static menus which is working.

My menu structure is like

```
Home

Services

        -ser1
        -ser2
        -ser3

About

    -abt1

Contact
```

All the menu values and hyperlink comes from json file.

This is my json

```
 [
    {
        "id": 100,
        "product": 0,
        "childs": [
            {
                "id": 200,
                "description": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Home",
                    "url": "home"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 100,
        "description": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "services",
            "url": "services"
        },
        "parent": null,
        "childs": [
            {
                "id": 200,
                "description": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Ser1",
                    "url": "Ser1"
                },
                "productCount": 0,
                "childs": [
                    {
                        "id": 250,
                        "description": {
                            "id": 0,
                            "name": "ser2",
                            "url": "Ser2"
                        },
                        "childs": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 251,
                        "description": {
                            "id": 0,
                            "name": "ser3",
                            "url": "ser3"
                        },
                        "productCount": 0,
                        "childs": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 201,
        "description": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "About",
            "url": "about"
        },
        "productCount": 0,
        "childs": [
            {
                "id": 203,
                "description": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "abt1",
                    "url": "underground"
                },
                "productCount": 0,
                "childs": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 202,
        "description": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Contact",
            "url": "con"
        },
        "productCount": 0,
        "childs": []
    }
]
```

And this is my HTML

```
<li class="prod-dropdown" ng-repeat="menu in menus" ng-class="{proddropdown: menu.menus}">
                    <a ng-href="#/{{menu.action}}" ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle': menu.menus}"
                       data-toggle="dropdown">{{menu.menus.desc['name']}} </a>
                    <ul ng-if="menu.menus" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.menus">
                            <a ng-href="#/{{submenu.action}}">{{submenu.desc}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You do not have even a single matching property defined in json and html

Comment: The values will come from php backend they are creating json dynamically.This is for ecommerce website

Comment: I am not talking about values but the properties. For instance, in json, I can not find anything like action

Comment: i need to create a menu like home,services,about,contact
And inside services menu there will be three submenus ser1,ser2,ser3
And inside about  menu there will be submenu abt1.And all the menu values will come from json

Comment: Try transforming your JSON into an array matching the structure of your `menu` object (using JS or PHP) and add it to your controller's `$scope`. If you have trouble after that point, update your question accordingly. You will likely run into issues with nested child menus; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15661289/3149036 when you need it.

Comment: You have the basic idea correct with the nested ng-repeats, you just need to match it to your JSON accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 level submenu

```
<li class="prod-dropdown" ng-repeat="menu in menus">
            <a ng-href="#/{{menu.description['url']}}" ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle': menu.menus}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{menu.description['name'] | uppercase}} <span ng-if="menu.childs" class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul ng-if="menu.childs" class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="submenu in menu.childs">
                    <a tabindex="-1" ng-href="#/products/{{submenu.description['url']}}">{{submenu
                        .description['name']}}</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="submenu.childs">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="subofsub in submenu.childs">
                            <a ng-href="#/products/{{subofsub.description['url']}}">{{subofsub.description['name']}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **ng-include** attribute - http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of "Dynamic multi level Menu"

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="sidebar-menu" ng-repeat="m in modulos">
      <li class="treeview" ng-repeat="(itemIndex, item) in modulos">
        <a ng-click="showSubmenu(itemIndex)">
          <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>{{item.module}}</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="sub-nav" ng-show="isShowing(itemIndex)">
          <li ng-repeat="sub_element in m.submodule">
            <a href="{{sub_element.url}}">{{sub_element.res}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $scope.showSubmenu = function(item) {
        if ($scope.activeParentIndex === item) {
          $scope.activeParentIndex = "";
        } else {
          $scope.activeParentIndex = item;
        }
      }

      $scope.isShowing = function(index) {
        if ($scope.activeParentIndex === index) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };

      $scope.modulos = [{
        "module": "Admin System ",
        "adm_modulo_id": 1,
        "submodule": [{
          "res": "Angular",
          "url": "#/admin/1"
        }, {
          "res": "Linux",
          "url": "#/admin/2"
        }, {
          "res": "Server",
          "url": "#/admin/3"
        }]

      }];
```

and the result is here in a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vrI2haNy1zYPDcCWh7gj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Review this page http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates, they made a multinivel menu since a json structure, no matter how many level do you have. And the example http://jsfiddle.net/NP7P5/1719/

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
        {{ category.title }}
        <ul ng-if="category.categories">
            <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.categories = [
  { 
    title: "Computers",
    categories: [
      {
        title: "Laptops",
        categories: [
          {
            title: "Ultrabooks"
          },
          {
            title: "Macbooks"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Desktops"
      },
      {
        title: "Tablets",
        categories: [
          { 
            title: "Apple"
          },
          {
            title: "Android"
          }
        ]        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Printers"
  }
];
});
```