# How do I create a dynamic nav which gets allowed menu items passed to it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For building the actual navigation, I like this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/xUsCc/1/, which I found here: [Recursion in Angular directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives), also created a follow up question here: [how do i bind a directive to an injected service instead of a parent or isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775263/how-do-i-bind-a-directive-to-an-injected-service-instead-of-a-parent-or-isolated)

The problem is that the directive gets its data from an attribute on the markup, which is a scope variable on the parent scope, like so:

```
<tree family="treeFamily"></tree>
```

The navigation bar sits outside the view, so there is no scope to get a variable from, other than the rootscope.

I was thinking that I could inject some factory/service that has the menu items the user is allowed to access. I tried setting a scope variable in the isolated scope, but that just killed any rendering. I guess angular doesn't like setting any variables in the isolated scope

```
    scope: {family: {
        name : "Parent",
        children: [{
            name : "Child1",
            children: [{
                name : "Grandchild1",
                children: []
            },{
                name : "Grandchild2",
                children: []
            },{
                name : "Grandchild3",
                children: []
            }]
        }, {
            name: "Child2",
            children: []
        }]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the recursive directive stuff initializing it from a model in the `$rootScope` seems to be the right solution.

If your menu has only two levels I would simply wrap it into a controller that gets its data from the `$rootScope` or adds to the `$rootScope` some methods allowing to control the items in your menu (e.g. `addSection()`, `remoteSection()`, etc).

Your could also use a `Service` to allow communication between your different components.

Comment: How would I use the service to get the data to my nav though? usually a controller would call the service to get the data, set the data on the scope, and then the markup would pass the scope variable to the directive. I don't have a controller to do all of that.

Comment: You can access $rootScope in the app.run() function.  Typically I configure things inside my rootscope (things that would otherwise be in a controller if root had a controller) inside .run().  For example app.run(function($rootScope) { // stuff in here });

Comment: yea, that seems to be the only way this will work.. which feels wrong.. but looks like that's how angularjs rolls

Comment: Both directives, services, run block and controllers can access to both $rootScope and any service. You are free to do what ever you want. Connecting components in Angular is very flexible. You can even use angular events.

Comment: It does feel a bit wrong.  I'd recommend taking a look at using angular-ui's $state / $stateProvider.  It allows you to use nested routing or "states" each of which can have a controller (or not).  As a result I then create a 'root' state which all other states are children of, then you get a controller for your root state and things feel a bit nicer.  It's really easy to access parent state's $scope from a child and vice versa.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router - the documentation on the wiki for ui-router is also very good.

Comment: @Mike would you mind posting the answer on the linked post here, also? It feels like we're hijacking this guy's answer.