# how do i bind a directive to an injected service instead of a parent or isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

related to this question: [How do I create a dynamic nav which gets allowed menu items passed to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774978/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-nav-which-gets-allowed-menu-items-passed-to-it)

Basically, I have a nav outside of any views. The nav needs to display menu items which a user has access to.

I create the nav markup with a directive like so:

```
<tree family="treeFamily"></tree>
```

Where `treeFamily` is the data which will be used to build the navigation menu.

However, since my nav is outside of any views, it doesn't have a controller, so there is no scope variable called `treeFamily`. Which means the directive doesn't get any data to create a navigation.

I originally thought I could just inject a service with the data for the menu items, but then there is no way that I can see to tell an angular directive to use data taken from an injected service for binding.

The only other way that seems to be possible is to have a $rootScope variable called treeFamily and have the directive generated markup bind to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a `$rootScope` variable here is a slightly hacky solution but you could get the scope by the element.

Example.

Say your data is applied to a test controller so you have a element like this

```
<div id="test" ng-controller="test">
```

You could do this example using jQuery (not required)

```
$('#test').scope().treeFamily
```

There it is you have access to the scope that you need to get your data from, demo in progress.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hq26h/**

In the demo the **random** directive is accessing the `treeFamily` data from the **test** controller when the directive is outside the controller.

If you wan't your service data to be bindable, you can do this

```
app.directive('something', function( $someNavDataService ) {
    return function( $scope ) {
       $scope.navData = $someNavDataService;
    }; 
});
```

Comment: While your answer does fit the criteria in the OP, this solution feels worse than putting it in the $rootScope. One thing that comes to mind, it would mean I would have to have some element with a controller just for the purpose of the nav. In which case, I could just assign a parent controller and pass the data in.

Comment: You don't have any data in a scope if you don't have a controller, so..... what? And incase you didn't see it, I said **here is a slightly hacky solution**

Comment: It looks like there is some miscommunication here. In the OP, any references to scope is simply me saying that the solution I found used an isolated scope for binding the data. **I'm trying to bind data that is passed into the directive via a service**. I had thought I could create a variable in the isolated scope and assign the data from a service to it. That doesn't work. So now I'm soliciting ideas for how I can create a directive with data from a service.

Answer (score 0):

I still think you want to have a look at angular-ui router, as mentioned I in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774978/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-nav-which-gets-allowed-menu-items-passed-to-it)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

However, the way I'd do this without angular-ui-router is to create the service, then just inject the service in to the directive when you declare that, and use the data in there as per http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

For example:

```
angular.module('yourModule').service('yourService', function() {
   // define your service
});

angular.module('yourModule').directive('yourDirective', function(yourService) {
  return {
     link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
       // you can now define your directive and access your yourService service
     }
  };
});
```