# Is it normal that the external template is not fully compiled while running the directive's link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-scope

Let's assume the directive `myDirective`: `<my-directive></my-directive>`.
When compiled, it should be replaced by the following external template:

```
<my-button>MyButtonLabel</my-button>
```

This `my-button` should be replaced at its own compilation by:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">MyButtonLabel</button>
```

So in a Jasmine test, I invoke the following:

```
element = angular.element(
                '<directive1></directive1>'
        );
compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
$scope.$digest();
console.log(compiledElement); //well displays: <button class="btn btn-primary">MyButtonLabel</my-button>
```

However, if I place this `console.log` in the `link` function itself of the `myButton` directive, I obtain:

```
<my-button>MyButtonLabel</my-button>
```

The `my-button` directive isn't recursively compiled !

Is this due to the manual `$scope.$digest();` in unit test that would allow the full compilation only at this moment?

In the contrary, when I don't deal with a unit test:
`link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) { console.log(elm);  //...`
displays the whole compilation.
I imagine this code is executed just before the `$scope.$digest();`, at this line:

```
compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
```

I don't think that a JSFiddle/Plunkr would be necessary.
Indeed, I just want to know whether it is a known case in unit testing.

Comment: No. I want see plunker with your directive defintion.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B26qU/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <my-directive></my-directive>   
<div>
```

**script**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile){
  return {    
    replace: true,    
    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,    
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.html('<my-button>MyButtonLabel</my-button>');           
            $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);         
    }
  };  
});

app.directive('myButton', function() {
  return {    
    restrict: 'E',
    template:'<button class="btn btn-primary">MyButtonLabel</button>',
    replace: true
  };  
});
```

### Jasmine Test

**[Jasmine Test Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39ekD/)**

```
describe('myApp', function () {
    var element;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
        element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            var scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        });
    });
    it('says MyButtonLabel', function () {
        expect(element.text()).toBe('MyButtonLabel');
    });
});
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56068/discussion-between-mik378-and-nidhishkrishnan).