# Delete the current node from list : AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piyushparate/akfvfc9v/)**
 link where we can add new child nodes, and their child node too, can delete the child node form the parent ONLY.

**I am trying to delete all the child node and ALSO the current node from the same delete button. (All child node are deleted successfully but i am not able to delete the current node from the list.)**

How can i do this via Angular Js.

```
    angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: []});
    };
    $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes: []}];
}]);
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: With your current function setup, I don't think you can.. I might be wrong.

Comment: So is there any other way? like can i reassign $scope.tree = $scope.tree by removing particular deleted triggered node

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14460332/123415 and http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/KNM4q/110/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursion in Angular directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the current node also, you need to remove it from the parent, therefore you will need to store reference to parent node in data

```
data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: [], parent: data});
```

Then in delete(), you can access parent node and remove itself:

```
$scope.delete = function(data) {
    var index = data.parent.nodes.indexOf(data);
    if(index > -1) {
        data.parent.nodes.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akfvfc9v/2/)