# how to create a menu in a recursive way Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to create a menu like this :

```
    Item1
         sublink1
                 sublink1-1
                 sublink1-2
         sublink2
         sublink3
                 sublink3-1
                           sublink3-1-1
                           sublink3-1-2
   Item2
        sublink1
        sublink2
                sublink2-1
                sublink2-2
        sublink3
                sublink3-1
                sublink3-2
  Item3
        sublink1
        sublink2
```

the menu structure may change according to our needs so how can i create a configurable menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've used when working on resursive in Angular.

[Recursion in Angular directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives)

http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/

https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat

http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=recursive

https://github.com/krispo/json-tree

Hope this helps.