# Angular tree directive with only one directive - too much recursion?

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive

I am trying to avoid writing the compile and/or link functions. I only want to use the controller function. Why am I getting "too much recursion"?

The data:

```
$scope.myTree = {
    name: "Root",
    id: 1,
    items: [
        {
            name: "Arts",
            id: 12,
            items: [
                { name: "Sculpture", id: 220 },
                { name: "Painting", id: 221 },
                { name: "Music", id: 222 }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Science",
            id: 45,
            items: [
                { name: "Biology", id: 345 },
                { name: "Chemistry", id: 346 },
                { name: "Physics", id: 347}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

The markup:

```
<tree data="myTree" labelfield="name" valuefield="id" childrenfield="items">
<div>
    This is the custom node content.
</div>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("tree", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            labelfield: "@",
            valuefield: "@",
            childrenfield: "@",
            data: "="
        },        
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.children = []; // remember - these are NOT the model's children!!!

            if ($scope.data[$scope.childrenfield] !== undefined) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data[$scope.childrenfield].length; i++) {
                    $scope.children.push({
                        label: $scope.data[$scope.childrenfield][i][$scope.labelfield],
                        value: $scope.data[$scope.childrenfield][i][$scope.valuefield]
                    });
                }
            }
        },      
        template: "<ul><li ng-transclude></li>" + 
                    "<li ng-repeat='child in children'> {{child.label}}" +
                        "<tree labelfield='labelfield' valuefield='valuefield' childrenfield='childrenfield'></tree>"   +
                    "</li>" +
                  "</ul>"
    };
});
```

If I remove the  tag in the template, it will show only the first level, otherwise, I'll get infinite recursion.

What is missing? What shouldn't be there?

Comment: create a plunker, will be easier

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that Angular _"cannot handle directives that recursively use themselves in their own templates"_.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that while you can't include the same directive inside itself, you can include another directive that includes the first one.

[angular ui tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) appears to do this with the TreeNode and TreeNodes directives.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a late answer, but I think some people will find this useful.]

Nested directives will cause that "too much recursion" error. You may use RecursionHelper from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives/18609594#18609594).

After adding `RecursionHelper` service to your angular module, you just need to compile your directive element using `RecursionHelper.compile` function.

```
compile: function(element) {
        // Use the compile function from the RecursionHelper,
        // And return the linking function(s) which it returns
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element);
    }
```