# Building Menu when nodes are not known in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Considering I am unaware of how many sub objects my parent object will have how can I create a menu using ng-repeat or any other method.

Let's say my object is:

```
var Obj=[{
    "node1":[{
         "Subnode1":[{
                "SubSubNode1":[{
                       ...
                    }]
              }]
    },{
        "Subnode2":[{ ... }]
    }]
},{
    "node2":[{ ... }]
}];
```

How can i create a menu for the above object using angularJS?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I was thinking how or from where do I start with? is there any possible way to do the same in AngularJS?

Comment: You may use nested 'ng-repeat's with bind-once (not necessary, for performance). If you cannot accomplish what you wish, people here will be helping you if you post your code.

Comment: I have added a plunker for your reference http://plnkr.co/edit/zAdS6qUoxQL5M0N2g6Ec?p=preview
and @Aniket nodes can be unlimited in a tree structure. need a solution which can have ng-repeats dynamic or some other inbuild directive which can help me out for this.

Comment: I found this link extremely efficient to do this ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/14460332/3214856 ). Just remove the delete functionality according to your need:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive `ng-repeat` using an `ng-include` template which goes something like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu-node.html">
  <markup-of-your-node>{{ node.name }}</markup-of-your-node>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="childNode in node.children" ng-include="'menu-node.html'">
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="node in menu.nodes" ng-include="'menu-node.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

To use this technique, you'll need to update your object to the following structure:

```
var nodes=[
  {
    "name": "node1",
    "children":[
      {
        "name": "Subnode1",
        "children":[
          {
            "name": "SubSubNode1",
            "children":[{ ... }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Subnode2",
        "children":[{ ... }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "node2",
    "children":[{ ... }]
  }
];
```

Comment: but each time it will traverse in menu.nodes only it will not go in its depth. i.e children nodes

Answer (score 0):

You need to know beforehand the depth of your subnodes.

Use nested `ng-repeat` to populate your menus.
Here's something to get you started on nested `ng-repeat`:

JS: `$scope.menu = obj; //pass your menu object to view`

HTML:

```
            <div ng-repeat="m in menu">
                ...
                <div ng-repeat="s in m">
                   ...
                   <div ng-repeat="sn in s">
                     ...
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/u75us/) from vojtajina doing exactly the same you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a directive for menu item and use it recursively along your nodes. Recursive directives will cause "too much recursion" error; so, you will need to use RecursionHelper from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives/18609594#18609594).

See the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GCYrB3NiW7U4lSTRzZc1?p=preview).

```
.directive("menuNode", function(RecursionHelper){

   return {
        scope: {
            menuNode: '=',
        },
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuNode track by $index">{{menuItem.label}}<div ng-if="menuItem.nodes" menu-node="menuItem.nodes"></div></li></ul>',
    compile: function(element) {
        // Use the compile function from the RecursionHelper,
        // And return the linking function(s) which it returns
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element);
    }
      };

})
```