# How to display a JSON tree as nested <ul>s with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Suppose I have a JSON tree structure as follows:

```
var myTree = {
  "node": {
    "name": "A",
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "B",
      },
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "C",
      },
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is just an example showing the structure of the tree. But in reality the tree might be much larger and it has an arbitrary (unknown) depth.

I want my angularJS app to display this as a set of nested `<ul>`s as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't care about the whitespace. All I really care about is that it appears as nested bullet points.

I have also created the following recursive function that converts the JSON into the correct HTML:

```
self.HTMLTree = function(jsonTree) {
  var retStr = '<li>' + jsonTree.node.name;
  if (('children' in jsonTree) && (jsonTree.children.length > 0)) {
    retStr += '<ul>';
    for (childIndex = 0; childIndex <= jsonTree.children.length - 1; childIndex++)
      retStr += self.HTMLTree(jsonTree.children[childIndex]);
    retStr += '</ul>';
  }
  retStr += '</li>';
  return retStr
}
```

In my HTML, I call it like this:

```
{{myCtrl.HTMLTree(myCtrl.myTree)}}
```

When I load this page, instead of seeing the bullets, I see the entire HTML returned by `HTMLTree()` rendered as text. Why? How do I make it render the actual bullets?

And is my way of constructing the HTML tree the right way to do it? It feels wrong. I feel like I should be able to somehow due it purely in the angular view file without coding HTML into my Javascript.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxhhvw7v/7/)

Comment: Use `return $sce.trustAsHtml(retStr)`. Also remember to inject $sce into your controller. Ideally you would use a directive for this, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives) for more info.

Comment: Hmmm, @ThomasGhesquiere, I tried that here but it didn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/qxhhvw7v/8/

Comment: See Shashank's answer, `<ul ng-bind-html="myCtrl.HTMLTree(myCtrl.myTree)"></ul>` was the missing key. (your fiddle was also missing a return statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way and find the sample code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/pj7L0v1L/).

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    Hello World!
    <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
        <ul ng-bind-html="myCtrl.HTMLTree(myCtrl.myTree)"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $sce) {
    var self = this;

    self.myTree = {
        "category": {
            "name": "A",
        },
        "children": [{
            "category": {
                "name": "B",
            },
            "children": []
        }, {
            "category": {
                "name": "C",
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }

    self.HTMLTree = function (jsonTree) {
        var retStr = '<li>' + jsonTree.category.name;
        if (('children' in jsonTree) && (jsonTree.children.length > 0)) {
            retStr += '<ul>';
            for (childIndex = 0; childIndex <= jsonTree.children.length - 1; childIndex++)
                retStr += self.HTMLTree(jsonTree.children[childIndex]);
            retStr += '</ul>';
        }
        retStr += '</li>';
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(retStr);
    }
});
```