# Recursion in Angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

There are a couple of popular recursive angular directive Q&A's out there.
An elegant solution is to abstracting the recursion functionality into a service
And call it at directive 'compile' phase :

[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives/18609594#18609594)

What is the best approach if I want to use the same concept in the new Angular 1.5 .component() instead of .directive()?

Comment: This is a little too broad of a question... you should try it in 1.5 and see what you think. And you have specific problems, ask in SO :).

Comment: @ajmajmajma I don't understand 2 things: 1) Why you gave me downvote. 2)If you understood my question.
1.5 .component() does not have 'compile'...
I think I'm beeing specific in my question

Comment: I did not downvote, however there are many ways to achieve recursion via a directive or component hence this is a broad and possibly opinion based question. You should give it a shot at least and show code if there are problems or questions.

Comment: So, How can I compile all the nested contents which are supposed to be the 'same' component? Recursively.

I know How I can achieve that with .directive(), I want to know How to apply same concept using 1.5 .component()

Comment: Either don't rely on compile - have the template itself recurse based on the passed data or just stick to directive(). I believe component exposes a few other methods you can work with if you are absolutely stuck with using component.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure what the confusion is... this is extremely simple to pull off.  Below is an example of a recursive component.

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.component('recursed', {
  template: [
    '<div class="container">',
      '<div>Contains {{$ctrl.depth}} layers</div>',
      '<recursed depth="$ctrl.depth-1" ng-if="$ctrl.depth"></recursed>',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''),
  bindings: {
    depth: '<'
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <h1>Recursion</h1>
  <recursed depth="5"></recursed>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Components are supposed to be more strict than directives (for simple directives).

They do not expose `compile` function.

this is from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

> When not to use Components:
>
> for directives that rely on DOM manipulation, adding event listeners etc, because the compile and link functions are unavailable
> when you need advanced directive definition options like priority, terminal, multi-element
> when you want a directive that is triggered by an attribute or CSS class, rather than an element

In other words - components don't replace directives, they inherit from them making it easier to build simple directives. You can still use directives to the task. They are **not** deprecated.