# AngularJS: How to calculate & print depth when iterate in data

Tags: angularjs

### I have a json exactly as follow:

```
[{"ID":1,"Name":"Suzy","ParentID":0},
{"ID":2,"Name":"Somi","ParentID":1},
{"ID":3,"Name":"Romi","ParentID":2},
{"ID":4,"Name":"Jumi","ParentID":3},
{"ID":5,"Name":"Gargi","ParentID":0},
{"ID":6,"Name":"Sujoy","ParentID":5},
{"ID":7,"Name":"Kamal","ParentID":6},
{"ID":8,"Name":"Joy","ParentID":0},
{"ID":9,"Name":"Sumana","ParentID":8},
{"ID":10,"Name":"Alex","ParentID":0}]
```

In my case, relation establish with ID and ParentID. The relation can be nested upto nth level. How to print depth when use ng-repeat to show parent and child relation.

### This way i tried

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-ng-controller= "MasterDetails" >
        <li
            data-ng-repeat="parent in details | filter: { ParentID: 0 }" >
            <a href="#/customers"> {{ parent.Name }} </a>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="child in details | filter: { ParentID: parent.ID }">
                    {{ child.Name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("MasterDetails", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.details = [{"ID":1,"Name":"Suzy","ParentID":0},
{"ID":2,"Name":"Somi","ParentID":1},
{"ID":3,"Name":"Romi","ParentID":2},
{"ID":4,"Name":"Jumi","ParentID":3},
{"ID":5,"Name":"Gargi","ParentID":0},
{"ID":6,"Name":"Sujoy","ParentID":5},
{"ID":7,"Name":"Kamal","ParentID":6},
{"ID":8,"Name":"Joy","ParentID":0},
{"ID":9,"Name":"Sumana","ParentID":8},
{"ID":10,"Name":"Alex","ParentID":0}];
}]);
```

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/s0svpaev/2/

Hierarchy should be look like this way with depth

```
Suzy 0
    Somi 1
        Romi 2
            Jumi 3
Gargi 0
    Sujoy 1
        Kamal 2
Joy 0
    Sumana 1
Alex 0
```

Just see my code and guide me how to calculate & print depth when iterate in data like 0,1,2...so on for nested data. There should be no data for depth in json rather it should be calculated on the fly. Can we use `$index` here to print the depth? Looking for idea. Thanks

Comment: For recursive nesting like this, I suggest creating a custom directive.  Otherwise your HTML will have a hard time defining enough nesting.

Comment: tell me how to calculate depth please....what code or logic i need to add there.

Comment: You should write a recursive directive that includes that information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion in Angular directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives)

Comment: i will re organise the array in controller side to already have depth level and then display it

Comment: reorganise the array to have a treeview in the controller ( each node know there child ). http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview