# Recursively including angular directives inside of each other with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a case where I need to include a directive inside of itself depending on an `ng-if` statement and `ng-repeat` filter, here is the current code:

**checkbox.html - directive**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="inputs[field.$id]"> {{field.label}}
<div ng-if="field.needsExplanation">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="field in fields | filter:{choice.explanationID}">
      <checkbox></checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see I am calling the `<checkbox>` directive inside of it's own directive (but it is selecting a different `field` object with an angular ng-repeat filter.)

When I run this it crashes the browser and generates the `$rootScope:inprog` error message.

Here is how the directive is being created:

```
app.directive('checkbox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/checkbox.html',
        scope: true
    };
});
```

How can I get it to output properly?

The output would be something like this:

```
[] Apples
```

If the checkbox is checked and it requires more details (field.needsExplanation)

```
[x] Apples
    [] Fiji
    [x] Granny
        [] Cheap
        [] Expensive
    [] Smith
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe give us an example of what output you expect to see?

Comment: Updated it with an example of output

Comment: @Jordash See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives), it should solve exactly what your problem is.