# How to fix “10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!” error in Angular 1.5 Components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am writing a angular component in recursive way to display a json as tree. It **works**, but Aborts showing **"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations"**

Component Template:

**jsonTree.html:**(recursive)

```
<span>{{$ctrl.key}}</span>
<span ng-if="!$ctrl.isExpandable">{{$ctrl.value}}</span>
<ul ng-if="$ctrl.isExpandable">
  <li ng-repeat="(subkey,subval) in $ctrl.value">
    <json-tree key="subkey" value="subval"></json-tree>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Component JS:**

```
myModule.component ('jsonTree',
    bindings: {key:"<",value:"<"}
    templateUrl: "jsonTree.html");
```

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives

Comment: Basically the reason you are getting infdigestloop error is that template compiler sees the directive inside your template and goes "oh let me compile that template too" and then tries to compile that template again and goes "oooh another directive let me compile it's template too" over and over again.

Comment: Thanks... Now I understand the problem...So, do you say to use directives instead of components for these kind of recursive use cases???

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)