# Recursive custom directives using ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a treeview using AngularJS.

Here's my code:

```
module.directive('treeview', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "/templates/ui/controls/treeview.htm",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("treeview directive loaded");
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $rootScope.depth = 0;
            $scope.items = [
                { text: "face" },
                { text: "palm" },
                {
                    text: "cake",
                    childitems: [
                        { text: "1 face" },
                        { text: "1 palm" },
                        { text: "1 cake" }
                    ]
                }
            ];
        }
    };
});

module.directive('treeviewItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "/templates/ui/controls/treeview-item.htm",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("treeview item directive loaded");
        }
    };
});
```

Treeview template:

```
<div class="sl-treeview">
    <ul class="clear" ng-transclude>
        <treeview-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item"></treeview-item>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Treeview Item template:

```
<li>
    <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
    <a href="/">
        <i class="icon-folder-close"></i>
        {{item.text}}
    </a>
    <!-- This ul is the issue - it crashes the page -->
    <ul>
        <treeview-item ng-repeat="childitem in item.childitems" item="childitem"></treeview-item>
    </ul>
</li>
```

In the treeview directive `$scope.items` is hardcoded for development - eventually I hope this will come from a controller/service pulling data from the server. However it represents the sort of basic structure I'm looking for.

When I run this without the nested ul in treeviewItem it gives me the first three items just fine. When i add the ul in to try and get the controls to bind with child items it hands the page and stops working.

JSFiddle without nested ul - working:

http://jsfiddle.net/BdmV3/

JSFiddle with nested ul - not working (and may hang your browser!):

http://jsfiddle.net/SKPpv/

How should I go about making a control that uses a custom directive and ngRepeat to create potentially infinite levels of recursion? Why isn't my approach working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to define your directive recursively, when angular was trying to compile the template, it saw `treeview` directive, it called `treeview`'s compile function, then it saw `treeviewItem` directive, it called `treeviewItem`'s compile function, then it saw `treeviewItem` directive, it called `treeviewItem`'s compile function,then it saw `treeviewItem` directive, it called `treeviewItem`'s compile function...

See the problem? The calls to compile functions couldn't stop. So, you need to pull the recursive definition out of your template, but use `$compile` to build DOM manually:

```
module.directive('treeviewItem', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<li><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i><a href="/"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i>{{item.text}}</a></li>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.append($compile('<ul><treeview-item ng-repeat="childitem in item.childitems" item="childitem"></treeview-item></ul>')(scope));

            console.log("treeview item directive loaded");
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SKPpv/3/

Alternatively, I found a solution to display tree-like data on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861030/69172. The solution however uses `ngInclude` instead of directives.

Comment: I came across $compile looking at other examples of treeviews and that was the option I took. It works beautifully. That you for the explanation of why my original approach doesn't work, it's obvious now! Out of interest, why are you watching `item.childitems`? Won't that add a ul for each child item?

Comment: @Jon I shouldn't use `$watch` like that in my original answer, it'll simple append another `ul` whenever `childitems` changes. I updated my answer without using `$watch`. Plus, can you share the treeview example you've found in your question so everyone can benefit more from your question?

Comment: @JamesKyle why does it no longer work? What error are you getting?

Comment: @EnigmaRM Updated angular in the jsFiddle posted above: http://jsfiddle.net/SKPpv/6/

Comment: @ye-liu If treeview cannot be inside a treeview, why ng-repeat inside a ng-repeat has no same problem? And all the offical directive. Is there some trick in it to avoid the endless recursion problem?