# AngularJS: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested array which I am ng-repeating on the page. By looking at the page, everything I want to show on the screen is rendered, however in the console I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

I assumed that this error occurs due to the amount of nested array's I have because once I make the size of my nested array smaller, the error doesn't appear.

[Here is a fiddle that models my situation](http://jsfiddle.net/NP7P5/32/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally solved the issue. What I ended up doing was adding a library called [Recursion Helper](https://github.com/marklagendijk/angular-recursion) to my project, and injected it as a dependency.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23404967/3229470) to the original post.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a known AngularJS issue. AngularJS itself prevents to many iterations to avoid infinite loops.

There is a possible workaround but it can harm other parts of your code:

```
$rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(15);
```

This changes the limit of the ten iterations to fifteen or whatever number you would like to.

http://jsfiddle.net/NP7P5/33/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however like you said, not too sure if doing this would be the best solution. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You welcome!
According to this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6440

It seems like there are not so much solutions to this