# How to convert my pen into angular tree-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview

I wrote simple [pen](http://codepen.io/dunmaksim/pen/GJLogo) with minimal functionality for working treeview a-la Material Design. But I not understand directives and can't write correct code for converting my templates into angular plugin.

How to write correct angular directive for treeview with async nodes loading and customizing checkboxes (show/hide)? Main problem for me now is error with  templates recursion.

**Markdown**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="treeview.html">
  <md-list-item>
    <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
    <md-icon class="material-icons md-secondary" ng-if="item.items" ng-click="toggleItems(item)">{{ item.expanded ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}</md-icon>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list flex ng-if="item.items" ng-show="item.expanded">
    <div ng-repeat="item in item.items" ng-include="'treeview.html'"></div>
  </md-list>
</script>

<body layout="column" ng-cloak ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl" flex>
  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2>TreeView emulation</h2>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>

  <md-content flex class="md-padding">
    <md-list>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'treeview.html'"></div>
    </md-list>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

**JS Code**

```
(function(A) {
  "use strict";

  var app = A.module('app', ['ngMaterial']),
    ids = 1;

  function getId() {
    return ids++;
  }

  function createItems(count) {
    var i, id, items = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
      id = getId();
      items.push({
        id: id,
        title: 'Item #' + id,
        items: id % 4
      });
    }
    return items;
  }

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = createItems(6); // 6 штук хвати всем!

    $scope.toggleItems = function(item) {
      if (item.items) {
        if (A.isArray(item.items)) {
          item.expanded = !item.expanded;
        } else {
          item.items = createItems(Math.floor(Math.random(4)) + 3);
          item.expanded = true;
        }
      }
    };
  }]);
}(this.angular));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Is it possible to make a Tree View with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854514/is-it-possible-to-make-a-tree-view-with-angular)

And also, take a look at this. It can be a good starting point.

https://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

Comment: Yes, I saw this links and write own directive, but she not work. Also, I copy code from this JSFiddle[1], but it's not a directive.

[1]http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/