# Infinite, never ending, nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following json object:

```
"comments": [
    {"username": "test", "comment": "This is a comment",
    "child": [
        {"username": "chriscool", "comment": "I replied to the above comment",
        "child": [
            {"username": "Anotherperson", "comment": "But what if I replied again",
            "child": [
                {"username": "ralphy", "comment": "And again?!" }
            ] }
        ] },
        {"username": "ralphy", "comment": "I also replied" }
    ] }
]
```

As you can see, each comment could have a `child` comment so it could literally go on forever. I am trying to display all of them but I can't figure out how I would do this.

This is all I have so far (obviously this only gets the first child in each comment):

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    {{ comment.comment}}
    <div ng-repeat="c in comments.child">
        {{c.comment}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd look for "recursion angular" on Google. Found this first result http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own directive that you can call recursively for your case

**Markup**

```
<div my-recursive-dir="comments"><div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myRecursiveDir', function(){
  return {
     templateUrl: 'Recursive.html',
     scope: {
        comments: '=',
     },
     replace: true
  };
});
```

**Recursive.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="c in comments.child">
    {{c.comment}}
    <div ng-if="c.child" my-recursive-dir="c"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: This for some reason performs and infinite loop that never stops and freezes the app

Comment: @bryan look at updated I changed..`<div ng-if="commets.child" my-recursive-dir="c"><div>` to `<div ng-if="c.child" my-recursive-dir="c"><div>` which will make finite loop

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `tree view`.

A good way is to print them not all at once, but only the first order comments, and add a button for loading the next ones (subcomments).

You can use a directive to do this, and encapsulate all the comments.

There is a good [stackoverflow question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854514/is-it-possible-to-make-a-tree-view-with-angular).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive that references itself:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      comment: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "myDirective.html"
  }
})

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
  {{ comment.comment }}
  <div ng-repeat="child in comment.child">
    <my-directive comment="child"></my-directive>
  </div>
</script>

<my-directive ng-repeat="comment in comments" comment="comment"></my-directive>
```