# Live updating tree view as a web application

Tags: javascript, java, sql, web-applications, treeview

I need to create a live updating tree view as a web application. I was wondering what steps I should take to learn to do this, what kind of framework I should set up, and what different languages it would be recommended to do this in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but typically a front end orientated language would be best suited for this type of action.

For instance, the following link:
[Tree View with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854514/is-it-possible-to-make-a-tree-view-with-angular)
shows how Angular could be used.

You should be able to find more examples if you search for Tree View on this site.